# How can I decouple the UI from the URL using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The following is a nested route I'm trying to configure in react-router:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="student/:studentId" onEnter={checkAuth} component={Student}>
        <Route path="edit" onEnter={checkAuth} component={StudentForm} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

The `student/:studentId` url should display all the details of that specific `studentId`.

The nested `student/:studentId/edit` should display a form to edit the previously displayed values.

What I'd like to avoid is to have to nest the `StudentForm` component inside the `Student` component, and display the form directly inside `App`.

I've been reading all the docs in `react-router` repo, especially this one: [Decoupling the UI from the URL](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#decoupling-the-ui-from-the-url), but it explains exactly the opposite (how to keep a component nested inside another but reachable by a different url).

I could check if the url is `edit` and render the form instead of the list of students, but I'd like it to avoid conditional rendering.

Is anyone aware of a way of achieving this using `react-router`?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the solutions is as simple as not nesting the routes in the router configuration:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="student/:studentId" onEnter={checkAuth} component={Student}>
    <Route path="student/:studentId/edit" onEnter={checkAuth} component={StudentForm} />
</Route>
```

This configuration will not nest components.